# CSS and Bootstrap don't work in laravel5.8. How can I fix this?

Tags: php, css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, load

I am using laravel 5.8. And I got a huge problem.
CSS and Bootstrap cannot be read.

1.I did **rm storage** because I wanted to make **php artisan storage:link** work. Finally I couldn't.

2.After **php artisan serve** did not work, so I changed to **chdir('/');** in ServeCommand.php.

3.Also I changed to

```
$this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
            return base_path('PATH TO PUBLIC FOLDER');
          });
```

in AppServiceProvider.php

4.Now **php artisan serve** is working but CSS and BootStrap cannot be loaded.

This is my index.blade.php (landing page, all links are pasted in this file)

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC:400,700|Work+Sans:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('external/fonts/icomoon/style.css')}}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('external/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('external/css/magnific-popup.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('external/css/jquery-ui.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('external/css/owl.carousel.min.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('external/css/owl.theme.default.min.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('external/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('external/css/animate.css')}}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mediaelement@4.2.7/build/mediaelementplayer.min.css">



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="external/fonts/flaticon/font/flaticon.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('external/css/aos.css')}}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('external/css/style.css')}}">
```

[This is my file structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yi3lu.png)

[This is my file structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVuGo.png)

I created **external** folder in public folder.

If someone knows solution, please help me out.

[Here is my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHeH6.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Could you post the console errors from your browser? It should show some errors for unfound resources.

Comment: I posted, thank you.

Comment: Inspect the page and check the url or href of an imported CSS file, sorry I should have been clear and just said "I'm trying to see if your import URLs are dodgy for some reason".

Comment: Also, instead of using `php artisan serve`, try using `php -S localhost:8000 -t public/`

Comment: Hi, but I still cannot make sense why it works. I have a vue icon in tab. I integrated Vue in this project. Is it related to this solution ?

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know what you exactly want to achieve, I am asuming you want to load files from the `public/external` directory.

If you have a clean Laravel 5.8 install 
`{{asset('external/css/bootstrap.min.css')` should work out of the box. So I should delete the `app->bind` stuff and try to use

`{{asset('external/css/bootstrap.min.css')`

see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-asset

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work. I want to achieve to make CSS and Bootstrap work. Thank you.

Comment: But did you remove the `$this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
            return base_path('PATH TO PUBLIC FOLDER');
          });` in the AppServiceProvider ?

Comment: Try a clean install.